# Is there a clear command to show the latest installed kernel on the system?

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, version

I'm looking for a command that lists me the latest kernel installed on a (Debian) system. For example `grub-mkconfig` "somehow" knows what the latest kernel version is. How does it achieve that? I know I can see it by looking but is there a command that can interpret the versions correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `sort -V` which is commonly available on Linux systems; it sorts version numbers:

```
ls /boot/vmlinuz-* | sort -V
```

or even

```
ls -v /boot/vmlinuz-*
```

if your `ls` supports that.

To only see the latest, keep the last line only:

```
ls -v /boot/vmlinuz-* | tail -n 1
```

That’s pretty much how `grub-mkconfig` goes about it; see `/usr/lib/grub/grub-mkconfig_lib` for the details.